Connect front-end with backend in MERN stack web application
Github link repo
It's a simple stock management system which based on MERN stack. There are two folders in this repo (frontend and backend). It works fine in local host but Now I uploaded to internet (Netlify, Render) its not working. Frontend link https://stockmanagement-aakash.netlify.app/ and backend link https://stock-system-1-h76n.onrender.com In backend link, If you add /api/products at the end of the link then you would be able to see the data from database. But its not working for frontend.
After watching a video, I have added a proxy in my frontend folder vite.config.js file which looks like server: { proxy: { '/api': 'http://localhost:3000', },  }, But it still not woking.

Verify that your backend API endpoints are accessible from the internet. You mentioned that appending /api/products to your backend URL works, so the issue may be related to how your frontend is making requests or how the proxy is configured
